# Find the value of polynomial at some K different integers, modulo 786433

Tags: c++, number-theory

You are given a polynomial of degree ***N*** with integer coefficients. Your task is to find the value of this polynomial at some ***K*** different integers, modulo ***786433***.

**Input**

The first line of the input contains an integer ***N*** denoting the degree of the polynomial.

The following line of each test case contains ***(N+1)*** integers denoting the coefficients of the polynomial. The ith numbers in this line denotes the coefficient ***a_(i-1)*** in the polynomial ***a_0 + a_1 × x_1 + a_2 × x_2 + ... + a_N × x_N***.

The following line contains a single integer ***Q*** denoting the number of queries.

The jth of the following ***Q*** lines contains an integer number ***x_j*** denoting the query.

**Output**

For each query, output a single line containing the answer to the corresponding query. In other words, the jth line of the output should have an integer equal to ***a_0 + a_1 × x_j + a_2 × x_j^2 + ... + a_N × x_j^N*** modulo ***786433***.

**Constraints and Subtasks**

- 0 ≤ a_i, x_j < 786433
- Subtask #1 (37 points): 0 ≤ N, Q ≤ 1000
- Subtask #2 (63 points): 0 ≤ N, Q ≤ 2.5 × 10^5

**Example**

Input:
2
1 2 3
3
7
8
9

Output:
162
209
262

**Explanation**

**Example case 1.**

- Query 1: 1 + 2 × 7 + 3 × 7 × 7 = 162
- Query 2: 1 + 2 × 8 + 3 × 8 × 8 = 209
- Query 3: 1 + 2 × 9 + 3 × 9 × 9 = 262

Here is the code that runs in O(n log n) time. I use Fast Fourier Transform to multiply the two polynomials.

Why do I need to use the modulo 786433 operator for all calculations? I understand that this might relate to int overflow? It this normal in competitive programming questions?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define all(a) (a).begin(),(a).end()
#define pb push_back
#define sz(a) ((int)(a).size())
#define mp make_pair
#define fi first
#define se second

typedef pair<int, int> pint;
typedef long long ll;
typedef vector<int> vi;

#define MOD 786433
#define MAGIC (3*(1<<18))

const int root = 10;

void fft(vi &a, int wn = root)
{
    int n = sz(a);
    if (n == 3)
    {
    int a1 = a[0] + a[1] + a[2];
        int a2 = (a[0] + a[1] * 1LL * root + a[2] * (root * 1LL * root)) % MOD;
        a[1] = a1;
        a[2] = a2;
        return;
    }

    vi a0(n / 2), a1(n / 2);
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i<n; i += 2, ++j)
    {
        a0[j] = a[i];
        a1[j] = a[i + 1];
    }
    int wnp = (wn * 1LL * wn) % MOD;
    fft(a0, wnp);
    fft(a1, wnp);

    int w = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i<n / 2; ++i) {
        int twiddle = (w * 1LL * a1[i]) % MOD;
        a[i] = (a0[i] + twiddle) % MOD;
        a[i + n / 2] = (a0[i] - twiddle + MOD) % MOD;
        w = (w * 1LL * wn) % MOD;
    }
}    

int n;
vi coef;

void poly(stringstream& ss)
{
    ss >> n;
    n++;
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        int x;
        ss >> x;
        coef.pb(x);
    }
    while (sz(coef)<MAGIC)
        coef.pb(0);

    vi ntt = coef;
    fft(ntt);

    vector<pint> sm;
    sm.pb(mp(0, coef[0]));
    int pr = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i<sz(ntt); i++)
    {
        sm.pb(mp(pr, ntt[i]));
        pr = (pr * 1LL * root) % MOD;
    }
    sort(all(sm));

    int q;
    ss >> q;
    while (q--)
    {
        int x;
        ss >> x;
        int lo = 0, hi = sz(sm) - 1;
        while (lo<hi)
        {
            int m = (lo + hi) / 2;
            if (sm[m].fi<x)
            lo = m + 1;
            else
            hi = m;
        }
        printf("%d\n", sm[lo].se);
    }
}


void test1()
{
    stringstream ss;
    {
        int degree = 2;
        ss << degree << "\n";
        string coefficients{ "1 2 3" };
        ss << coefficients << "\n";
        int NoQueries = 3;
        ss << NoQueries << "\n";
        int query = 7;
        ss << query << "\n";
        query = 8;
        ss << query << "\n";
        query = 9;
        ss << query << "\n";
    }
    poly(ss);
}

int main()
{
    test1();
    return 0;
}
```

BTW.: This [question](https://www.codechef.com/JULY16/problems/POLYEVAL) is from the July 2016 challenge @ code chef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re

> **”** Why do I need to use the modulo 786433 operator for all calculations? I understand that this might relate to int overflow? It this normal in competitive programming questions?

Yes, it's to avoid overflow.

And yes, it's normal in programming problem sets and competitions.